# Tratar con paréntesis en una calculadora

Tags: java

Se intenta hacer tan solo 4 tipos de operaciones básicas, desconozco como tratar la excepción que se produce al introducir operaciones como esta: -12+11, el signo negativo de delante da problemas, mientras que si se usa +12+11 funciona perfectamente.
También me da problemas el manejo de paréntesis en casos como "(‐(‐5))*  (‐4)".
Se agradecen sugerencias de mejora.

```
package calculadora;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class calculadora2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner tec = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca una operación: >>");
        String numero = tec.nextLine();
        numero=limpiaCadena(numero);
        opera(numero);
        tec.close();
    }
    public static String opera (String numero){
        double num1 = 0;
        double num2 = 0;
        //Se busca en el String que simbolo contiene
        if(numero.contains("+")){
            //Se hace un Split para dividir al String
            String[] array = numero.split("\\+");
            num1 = Double.valueOf(array[0].trim());
            num2 = Double.valueOf(array[1].trim());
            System.out.println("La suma es: " + (num1+num2));
        }else if(numero.contains("-")){
            String[] array = numero.split("-");
            num1 = Double.valueOf(array[0].trim());
            num2 = Double.valueOf(array[1].trim());
            System.out.println("La resta es: " + (num1-num2));
        }else if(numero.contains("*")){
            String[] array = numero.split("\\*");
            num1 = Double.valueOf(array[0].trim());
            num2 = Double.valueOf(array[1].trim());
            System.out.println("La multiplicación es: " + (num1*num2));
        }else if(numero.contains("/")){
            String[] array = numero.split("/");
            num1 = Double.valueOf(array[0].trim());
            num2 = Double.valueOf(array[1].trim());
            System.out.println("La division es: " + (num1/num2));
        }else{
            System.out.println("Use el formato (a+b),(a-b),(a/b) o (a*b).");
            main(null);
        }
        main (null);
        return null;
    }
    public static String limpiaCadena(String numero){ 
        numero=numero.replace("((","");
        numero=numero.replace("))","");
        numero=numero.replace("(","");
        numero=numero.replace(")","");
        numero=numero.replace("++","+");
        numero=numero.replace("--","+");
        numero=numero.replace("+-","-");
        numero=numero.replace("-+","-");
        numero=numero.replace(" ","");
        return numero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Este es el clásico [problema de balanceo de paréntesis](http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=116&punto=&inicio=40). Recomendación: primero evalúas si la fórmula ingresada es correcta, de no serlo muestras un mensaje de error y no haces nada más. Si está correctamente balanceada, pasas a parsear la fórmula como una expresión, usando la notación post fija o pre fija.

Comment: Si tienes tiempo para tu proyecto te recomendaría que uses el algoritmo de shutting yard,  este algoritmo se encarga de analizar algo como "45+23*14-5" y además se encarga de hacer las operaciones en el orden correcto.

Comment: @FrikyEquisDe Me encantaría disponer de los conocimientos para implementar dicho algoritmo, pero de momento lo veo demasiado. Gracias :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Le estoy echando un vistazo al enlace, pero podría aprovecharme de que tan solo nos piden operaciones entre dos variables. Creo que debería tener una solución más sencilla. Gracias!

Comment: Bueno, no hay peor ciego que el que no quiere ver...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Cierto, pero se agradece el enlace... El problema es que no tengo tiempo en estas fechas de examenes finales. Pero dentro de unas semanas seguro que lo hago.